# ListView for each item of list

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, view

i have 7 elements in ListView. i want to make so, that when i push on each item, it should  summon different classes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

for first item should be

```
intent(MainActivity,this, NewActivity.class)
```

,  for second intent

```
(this,  AnotherActivity.class)
```

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought to do the needful in the adapter of your class in `getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` function. Here code can be managed well.

getView() implementation can be like this -

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
View v1 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.id_v1);
View v2 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.id_v2);
.....
.....
View v6 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.id_v6);
View v7 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.id_v7);
v1.setOnClickListener(this);
v2.setOnClickListener(this);
.....
.....
```

OnClickListener implementation in the adapter class -

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    switch(v.getId() {

    case R.id.id_v1: intent(MainActivity,this, NewActivity.class);break;
    case R.id.id_v2: (this,  AnotherActivity.class); break;
    ....
    ....        

    }

   }
```